# Filter not working in model object - swift

Tags: swift

Basically my model object contains another model object and i want search/filter from model which is inside the main model object, please check below for more clarifications.

```
struct User {
    var name: String!
    var age: Int!
    var hasPet: Bool!
    var pets: [Pets]!
}

struct Pets {
    var id: Int!
    var petName: String!
    var colour: String!
}
```

Here when my final model object is created in that model i want filter which should filter main model based on what pet name user enter.

For example if one user in model have 2 pets one with black colour and second with white colour.
Then second user in model have 2 pets one with grey colour and one with brown colour.

Now when user search for Users who have white colour pet can come up in list. As in this case list will show first user. like that.

I have tried below code but it's not working ::

```
let petsFiltered = users.filter { (user) -> Bool in
    return (user.pets.)!
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: @rmaddy was my description is not enough to understand problem?

Comment: Nope, not at all. You first give a vague overview of what's in your data model. Then you give an even less clear sentence about what should happen when a user searches. Then you show a tiny bit of code and simply state "doesn't work". In what way exactly doesn't that code work? What do you actually do with `petsFiltered`? There are a lot of missing details in your question.

Comment: I don't understand. `pets["name"]` that means that `pets` is a Dict (because I don't think you did a subscript on `Pets`). You check for "white" on "name"? Your array is named `user` but you name the each var in it `pet`. So it should at least be `{ (anUser) -> Bool in`

Comment: @rmaddy Okay, may be this is because i have posted question for the very first time and from next time will take care of this. Thanks BTW!

Comment: @Larme yeah, you are right, users is main madel array which we need to filter and it will be like :: users.filter { (user) -> Bool in

Comment: @Larme but when i am trying to apply filter it's giving me error like ,

return (category.items)
Cannot convert value of type '[Pets]' to closure result type 'Bool'

Comment: @AakashPrajapati No need to wait until next time. You should [edit] this question  with the needed clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your structs:

```
struct User {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    var hasPet: Bool
    var pets: [Pet]
}

struct Pet {
    var id: Int
    var petName: String
    var colour: String
}
```

User and pets objects:

```
 let pet1 = Pet(id: 1, petName: "Lucy", colour: "black, white")
 let pet2 = Pet(id: 2, petName: "Nemo", colour: "white")
 let pet3 = Pet(id: 3, petName: "Scooby-Doo", colour: "white")
 let pet4 = Pet(id: 4, petName: "Garfield", colour: "brown, whiteerktjdfg")

 let user1 = User(name: "Joe", age: 20, hasPet: true, pets: [pet1, pet2])
 let user2 = User(name: "Sophia", age: 30, hasPet: true, pets: [pet3, pet4])

 let users = [user1, user2]
```

You can filter user who have white pets with below code:

```
    let whitePets = users.compactMap{user -> (User?) in
        var userWithWhitePets = user
        let pets = userWithWhitePets.pets.filter{$0.colour.contains("white")}
        userWithWhitePets.pets = pets
        return userWithWhitePets.pets.count > 0 ? userWithWhitePets : nil

    }
```

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments. You need to use "pets" like array instead dictionary and check *colour*. Something like that:

```
let usersFiltered = users.filter { (user) -> Bool in
    return user.pets.contains(where: { $0.colour == "white" })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think will be better for you also use a computed property for hasPet.

If not, each time that you add a first pet to the array or remove all elements from it, you will need to also update var hasPet: Bool.

```
 var hasPet: Bool{
    return pets.count > 0
}
```